# Does Haskell have a "de-facto" run-time type?

Tags: haskell

Here's my dilemma: 
When Haskell program gets compiled, binary executable machine code is generated that can be executed on a physical CPU. When Haskell program gets interpreted, physical CPU performs operations on data from memory locations. Execution realistically happens in some time period whose length depends on the CPU speed.

Since the data has been put into the memory by a compiler that guarantees that every variable is strongly typed, does this mean that Haskell effectively has a run-time type or not?

Clarification:
By "run-time type" I mean: the type (in type-theoretical sense) of a variable at the time when the program is executed on a physical processor reachable/identifiable by the language compiler at language compilation time.

Comment: What does 'run-time' type mean to you?  Can you give an example of something that would be a 'run-time' type and something that would not be a 'run-time' type?  Do you mean "Does Haskell have run-time type information?"

Comment: Run-time type = the type (in type-theoretical sense) of a variable at the time when the program is executed on a physical processor reachable/identifiable by the language compiler at language compilation time. Example: C++ with RTTI on and off. I guess you could get it down to how compiler uses run-time type information at compile time to decide if something compiles or not.

Comment: There is no information present about the types of data at run time.  Data representing an integer or tree or list is not "tagged" with any additional meta-data which indicates the type. All type checking is done at compile time. Because of this, unsafeCoerce and newtype wrapping/unwrapping have no runtime cost. This of course comes with the caveat that you can (explicitly) choose to store a representation of the type of data at runtime.

Comment: This is and implementation specific detail.  To properly answer your question the answerer needs to know (or assume) the compiler you are using.

Comment: @GrimMeme, what you mean by "run-time type" remains extremely unclear.

Answer (score 10):

Haskell's language features are designed to support *complete* type erasure. The idea is that the typing rules *guarantee* that code which passes type checking has the following two properties<sup>1</sup>:

1. A value is of one type is never passed to an function expecting another type
2. A function that claims to handle values in some type will handle **any** possible value in that type

The 2nd property bears expanding on. Obviously partial functions like `fromJust` and `head` do not in fact handle any possible value; they explode At runtime if given the wrong value. But they explode in a "well-defined" way, after checking the assumptions they depend upon. It's not  possible to write code that attempts to access substructure in values which may not have that substructure, which might cause segmentation faults or interpret random pieces of memory as if they were a different kind of data.

So after type checking is successful, there's no need to store any type information in the compiled program. I cab just throw the types away. I have already proven that if I generate code which blindly performs operations on data assuming that it is of the required shape that nothing will in fact go wrong.

Example time!

```
data Foo = Foo Int String
data Bar = Bar Int String
```

Values of Foo and Bar will probably be represented in memory identically<sup>2</sup>; once you know all values are type correct, all the information needed to define these values is an `Int` and a `String` in each case. If you were to look at a memory dump of a running Haskell program, you would not be able to tell whether a given memory object containing a reference to an `Int` and a `String` was a `Foo` or a `Bar` (or indeed a `(Int, String)`, or any other single constructor type with two fields that are `Int` and `String` respectively).

So no, Haskell types do not exist at runtime, in any form.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can of course break these properties using unsafe features, like `unsafeCoerce`; I'm talking about "normal" Haskell code here.

2 Or they may not. Haskell-the-language makes no guarantees at all about representation at runtime, and it would be perfectly possible for it to store the fields in a different order, or do something else that could distinguish the two. But I'm going to presume that in the absence of any reason to do otherwise, it treats these two types the same.

Answer (score 7):

Run-time type information is commonly found in OOP languages implementations, which carry a "type tag" with every object. Having such information enables one, for instance, to write code such as

```java
void foo(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof SomeClass) {
     ...
  }
}
```

which is a form of run-time type checking. The "type tag" often comes for free, since every object needs a pointer to the Virtual Method Table and that alone identifies the run-time type of the object.

In Haskell, though, there is no need for such a tag, or for pointers to VMTs. The language was designed without any kind of `instanceof` operator so that implementations do not have to provide any type tag at run-time. This also leads to a nicer underlying theory, since we get parametricity guarantees on code, also known as "theorems for free!". For instance the following function

```
f :: [a] -> [a]
f = .... -- whatever
```

can *not* be implemented so that `f [1,2] = [2,3]`. This is because there is, provably, no way to produce `3` for `f`. The intuition is that `f` must produce an `a`, and it can not check that `a=Int` at run-time (no type tags), so the output of `f` can only include elements found in its input. This guarantee comes only from the above typing, without even caring about how `f` is actually implemented.

If you really want an `instanceof` equivalent, you can use `Typeable` for that:

```
f :: Typeable a => [a] -> [a]
f [] = []
f (x:xs) = case cast x of
           Just (y :: Int) -> [2,3]
           Nothing         -> x:x:xs
```

This will return `[2,3]` on all nonempty lists if integers. At run-time, a type tag will be passed so that `a=Int` can be checked.

Answer (score 6):

The "run-time types" used in *any* compiled program, regardless of source language, are the types natively supported by the target processor:  typically integers (signed and unsigned), pointers (really just a special usage of integers), and floating-point numbers (typically [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)).  The compiler translates all the operations in the source program into an equivalent series of operations using these basic hardware-supported types.

More-sophisticated data types (such as Haskell's lists) are represented at run-time as data structures built from basic types.  For example, each node in a list may be represented by a pair of pointers:  one to the value held by that node (or a thunk for computing it), and one to the next node (or a thunk).  The compiler's static type-checking allows it to ensure that each of these run-time data structures is accessed only by code that will handle it properly.  For example, a region of memory that holds a pair of pointers for a list node won't be mistakenly treated as a thunk for computing an integer, because the compiler only allows the list to be passed to functions that expect a list argument.

Answer (score 1):

No.  A fundamental property of Haskell is that `newtype` declarations, like

```
newtype MyInt = MyInt Int
```

have no run-time overhead, which means that the constructor `MyInt` can literally return the same argument (whatever that is) that it was passed, and the compiler will treat it like a different type.  (If you look at the compiled code, after optimization you won't see any instructions to implement the `MyInt` function call, even.)  This means that any 'de-factor' run-time type of an object in Haskell would only be defined up to the equivalence between a `newtype` and its implementation.

Comment: To amplify this answer slightly, this means it is possible for two variables of different types to be physically represented by the exact same value in memory. So, it does not make sense to talk about "*the* type (in type-theoretical sense)" of a run-time value.